# Perl split a string using a string based delimiter

Tags: regex, perl, variables, split, delimiter

I'm brand new to Perl, but based on the documentation that I have read, it looks like the split function in Perl asks for a regex pattern rather than a string delimiter as the first parameter, but I found that using something like `print +(split(' ', $string))[0]` will still split the string correctly.

Based on that, I was trying to use a variable delimiter (ex. `print +(split($var, $string))[0]` where `$var = ' '`) and found that it did not work. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

EDIT:
Sorry for the terrible question. I was running this against a string with leading spaces and found that the split function didn't like the leading spaces. For example:

`my $var = ' ';
print +(split($var, '    abc ddddd'))[0]`
gives a blank output. Is $var being interpreted as `/$var/` inside the split function?

versus

`print +(split(' ', '    abc ddddd'))[0]`
which gives an output of `abc`

So when I read the docs I was assuming my variable would be considered a literal string, when in reality it was not, and therefore the leading whitespace was not stripped.

Comment: Works fine ... https://eval.in/240865

Comment: Any time you have a question about one of Perl's built-in functions, I highly recommend you check `perldoc`. If it's installed on your system, you can run `perldoc -f <function>`, or in this case, [`perldoc -f split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) (I linked to the online version for convenience). The documentation is excellent. Your uncertainty about `split` using regex vs. string is explained in detail, including the special case of `split ' '`.

Comment: **What does "doesn't work" mean?** "Doesn't work" is an inadequate description for us to understand the problem.  What happened when you tried it?  Did you get an error message?  Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Comment: Because `split ' '` will use a literal space as delimiter, invoking the special case described in the perldoc. `$var = ' '; split $var` will be equivalent of `split / /`, which is a regex split, not the same thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Explanation

When you split on a literal space

```
split ' '
```

You invoke the special case, described in [the documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html). When you use a variable

```
my $var = ' ';
split $var;
```

It is the same as putting that variable inside a regex:

```
split /$var/;
```

This will split on single whitespace, not the same thing. If for example you have this code:

```
my $string = "foo bar   baz";
my @literal = split ' ', $string;
my @space = split / /, $string;
```

Then `@literal` will contain `"foo", "bar", "baz"`, and `@space` will contain `"foo", "bar", "", "", "baz"` -- empty fields where it has split on the single spaces.

---

### Documentation

This is how the documentation describes it:

> As another special case, split emulates the default behavior of the command line tool awk when the PATTERN is either omitted or a literal string composed of a single space character (such as ' ' or "\x20" , but not e.g. / / ). In this case, any leading whitespace in EXPR is removed before splitting occurs, and the PATTERN is instead treated as if it were /\s+/ ; in particular, this means that any contiguous whitespace (not just a single space character) is used as a separator. However, this special treatment can be avoided by specifying the pattern / / instead of the string " " , thereby allowing only a single space character to be a separator. In earlier Perls this special case was restricted to the use of a plain " " as the pattern argument to split, in Perl 5.18.0 and later this special case is triggered by any expression which evaluates as the simple string " " .

### Workaround

Note that if you are looking for a way to dynamically emulate the `' '` splitting by using a variable, you might use `/\s+/` instead. It is not quite the same, in that it will not strip leading whitespace, but otherwise should work as expected.

Comment: Thank you! And way to understand my issue exactly :)

Comment: This seems to have changed in newer Perl versions. Currently, `split ' '` behaves exactly the same way as `split $var` where `$var=' '`. If you want the behavior similar to `split / /`, you should define `$var=qr/ /`.

Answer (score 0):

your code works fine, I think

```
my $text = "botolo";
my $separator = "o";
print +(split($separator, $text))[0];  
#uglyness with + necessary because Perl
```

Although, at the cost of one extra line, I would rather write that last line as:

```
my @parts = split($separator, $text);
print $parts[0];
```